# Redeclaring a class in PHP

Tags: php

I need to include two files which contain classes with the same name. I was hopeful when I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658906/is-there-any-way-to-redeclare-a-class-safely-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top) using `namespaces`. but since both classes extend the same parent class I get an error saying MyNamespce/Parent not found.

### MyClass.php

This is a shared resource that I cannot change.

```
// MyClass.php
class MyClass extends Parent {
  const MY_CONST = 1;
  ...
}
```

### MyNamespaceMyClass.php

I have some discretion on what to name things but I would like to keep changes minimal as this is a generated file.

```
// MyNamespaceMyClass.php
namespace MyNamespace;
class MyClass extends Parent {
   const MY_CONST = 2;
   ...
}
```

### example.php

Finally the code where I use classes:

```
// example.php
require_once 'MyClass.php';
require_once 'MyNamespaceMyClass.php';

/**
 * Converts My Class into the newer version.
 *
 * @param MyClass $my_class.
 * @return MyNamespace\MyClass
 */
 function convert_myclass(MyClass $my_class) {
   $new_my_class = new MyNamespace\MyClass();
   ...
   return $new_my_class;
 }
```

The problem is that I get `Fatal error: Class 'MyNamespace\MyClass' not found in MyNamespaceMyClass.php`. Is there a way to use namespaces to import identically named classes, which also extend from the same class?

Comment: Have you tried `class MyClass extends \Parent`

Comment: typo? ``namespace Mynamespace;`` later you use ``MyNamespace\MyClass();`` in which the namespace has a N

Comment: That was more of a typo in my questions; just fixed it. Tell me more about `extends \Parent` idea does that force it to look in the top level namespace?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it's looking for `MyNamespace\Parent` which won't exist.